# "skip coords" and "xticklabels from file" cause wrong labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

When filtering data from a file (with `skip coords between index` for example) and loading the x tick labels from the same file, the x tick labels are not skipped, leading to wrong labels.

As an example, consider the code shown below. In the file, we have 3 rows with data, with names `A`, `B` and `C`. We remove the row containing `B` with the `skip coords` key.
However, the resulting plot still shows the `B` label, however for the y value of `C`.

Is there a way to correct this issue?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
        id name val
        1 A 1
        2 B 2
        3 C 3
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{testdata.dat}\data

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        xtick=data,
        ymin=0,
        skip coords between index={1}{2}, % remove second row ("B")
        x filter/.append code={ % equivalent to the skip coords code, with same problem
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{id}\of{\data}
            \ifnum\pgfplotsretval=2
                \def\pgfmathresult{}
            \else
            \fi
        },
        xticklabels from table={\data}{name}, % xticklabels still contain "B"
    ]
        \addplot table[x=id, y=val] {\data};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

incorrect version:

[image: Imgur]

correct version:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: The data and the labels are not connected. So it is not meant to be used this way. If you want to remove a row then you need to remove explicitly with a coordinate filter.

Comment: Hi percusse, thank you for your answer. I modified the code to use an `x filter`, which shows the same problem (when commenting the `skip coords` line).
Do you have an idea what I can change in the filter to show the correct behavior?

Comment: Ah my mistake, I mean you shouldn't get the labels from table explicitly. You need to use the table as a whole with symbolic explicit points.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean with symbolic explicit points? Do you mean specifying the labels directly in the plot, as in `xticklabels={A,C}`? I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to correct the labels. The idea is to store the column with the names in a list, and then index the list with the tick number to print the correct label.

The code produces the correct version shown above.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
        id name val
        1 A 1
        2 B 2
        3 C 3
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{testdata.dat}\data
\pgfplotstablegetcolumn{name}\of\data\to\listnames % store column with names into \listnames

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        xtick=data,
        skip coords between index={1}{2}, % remove second row ("B")
        % xticklabels from table={\data}{name}, % xticklabels still contain "B"
        xticklabel=\pgfmathparse{int(\tick-1)} % need to subtract 1 because \tick starts with zero
            \pgfplotslistselect\pgfmathresult\of\listnames\to\myname % fetch name from list
            \myname, % print name
    ]
        \addplot table[x=id, y=val] {\data};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah very nice! I came here to paste a very similar solution

Comment: Thanks! I still believe that there must be a better solution than this...