# Grouped bargraph missing or shifted xlabel

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

Hello my bargraph is missing the x label for value 141 while the label for 117 seems to be shifted to the right.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{
Size;MinCount;MaxCount
82;2;1
84;1352;1135
88;1;1
89;18;18
90;1689;1448
95;1;1
96;4;4
105;2;2
106;1;1
108;46;41
110;2;2
113;1;1
115;1;1
116;14;18
117;0;1096
126;1;1
129;1;1
140;1;0
141;1313;0
}\realtable

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\scalebox{0.5}{
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{Messwerte/ChargingIO.csv}\datatable
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar = 0pt, 
    bar width = 10pt,
    x = 5ex,
    xtick = data,
    xticklabels from table = {\realtable}{Size},
    enlarge x limits = {abs = 1},
    ylabel={Allokationen},
        ymode = log,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        major grid style = {very thick},
        yminorgrids = true,
        minor grid style = {dashed, thick}, 
    ]
    \addplot table [x expr = \coordindex, y = {MinCount}]{\realtable};
    \addplot table [x expr = \coordindex, y = {MaxCount}]{\realtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption[...]{}
\label{dia:..}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is because your `MinCount` data at `x=117` contains a `0`.

Comment: You are right, its log scale! that was too obvious for me. Thank you

Comment: Is there a way to skip these values? i tried changing them to nan and inf in combination with unbounded coords=jump and discard but it doesnt seem to work?

Comment: What do you mean by skip the values ? Skip both bars at `x=117` ?

Comment: Well i would like to skip the bar with the value of 0 as the other bar is actually of interest.

Comment: An easy way could have been to plot fisrt your current second series of data, but it also contains `0` values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based on [the approach described by mdd here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220522/141947).

The idea is to store the list of `xitcklabels` and to typeset them manually, to avoid automatic discard by `pgfplots`. In addition to mdd's answer, here one has to also define the `xtick` manually, as you use `table[x expr=\coordindex]` in your plots.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{
Size;MinCount;MaxCount
82;2;1
84;1352;1135
88;1;1
89;18;18
90;1689;1448
95;1;1
96;4;4
105;2;2
106;1;1
108;46;41
110;2;2
113;1;1
115;1;1
116;14;18
117;0;1096
126;1;1
129;1;1
140;1;0
141;1313;0
}\realtable

\pgfplotstablegetcolumn{Size}\of\realtable\to\listnames % store column with names into \listnames
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\realtable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rowmax}{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar = 0pt, 
    bar width = 10pt,
    x = 5ex,
    xtick = {0,...,\rowmax},
    xticklabel={
        \pgfmathparse{int(\ticknum)}
        \pgfplotslistselect\pgfmathresult\of\listnames\to\tempxticklabel
        \tempxticklabel},
    enlarge x limits = {abs = 1},
    ylabel={Allokationen},
        ymode = log,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        major grid style = {very thick},
        yminorgrids = true,
        minor grid style = {dashed, thick}, 
    ]
    \addplot table [x expr = \coordindex, y = {MinCount}]{\realtable};
    \addplot table [x expr = \coordindex, y = {MaxCount}]{\realtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: @R.K perfect ! I also learned something here, so thanks for your question