# How to ensure correct locations of tick labels set by yticklabels?

Tags: pgfplots

I am making plots with two y-axes on two sides. To ensure that the curves do not overlap mutually, one of these axes is contracted and shifted to the bottom of the graph. So I modified `ymax` and specified `yticklabels`. But it occurred that tick labels are placed in wrong locations. How to fix it?

It seems that here is a bit similar problem, but I can't use the given solution: ["skip coords" and "xticklabels from file" cause wrong labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220424/skip-coords-and-xticklabels-from-file-cause-wrong-labels)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0.5,
    xmax=3.5,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=300,
    yticklabels={0,50,100,150,200},
]
\addplot [color=black]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
1   150\\
2   50\\
3   0\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the line:

```
ytick={0,50,...,200},
```

before the line of the `yticklabels`.

The output is:

[image]

You can also comment or cancel the line of `yticklabels`.